# How to return jqgrid data of selected rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In JQGrid

```
 var gridData=$("#SearchResults").jqGrid('getRowData')
```

The above line gives you the grid data of all the rows, is there a way where I can get the grid data of only the selected rows.

`selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid ('getGridParam', 'selrow'),`

The above gives the selected row IDs but I want the data as well of all the selected rows as it returns with gridData but I need only of those of selected one

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's very simple. The second optional option parameter of `getRowData` method is rowid of the row which data is requested (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods)). So you can use

```
var selRowId = myGrid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
```

to get last selected rowid first and then get the data of the row by

```
var rowData = myGrid.jqGrid("getRowData", selRowId);
```

If you use `datatype: "local"` or some remote `datatype` (`"xml"` or `"json"`), but with `loadonce: true` then jqGrid hold the data internally in `data` array. In the case the usage of `getLocalRow` method is more effective as the usage of `getRowData`:

```
var rowData = myGrid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", selRowId);
```

If you use `multiselect: true` option then jqGrid supports `selarrrow` array of selected rowids and you can get all required data in the loop:

```
var i, selRowIds = myGrid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow"), n, rowData;
for (i = 0, n = selRowIds.length; i < n; i++) {
    rowData = myGrid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", selRowIds[i]);
    // one can uses the data here
}
```

Comment: in version 4.5.4, this doesn't return the correct row data, if the grid is sorted differently from original data. also `id` is the selected rows, id in `onSelectRow: function (id, status, e) { ... }`

Comment: @AaA: I'm sure that your are wrong. I suppose that you misunderstand what is rowid. Many newcomers mix the row index with rowid and additionally fill the grid in the wrong way (without specifying the id in the input data). I'd recommend you to post new question with the demo which demonstrates your problem. Additionally I'd recommend you to upgrade retro version 4.5.4 (which is more as 4 years old) to [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.15.2.

Comment: Thank you Oleg, I knew that. I think I mis-phrased it. I was refering to `selRowId` in your solution which is equal to `id` in `onSelectRow` event. in version 4.5.4 it returns incorrect row, however it is working correctly in 4.15.2.

Comment: @AaA: You are welcome! Upgrade to 4.15.2 should improve the performance additionally. I strictly recommend you the upgrade independent on your current problem. I still not sure that version 4.5.4 contains the bug in `getLocalRow`. I suppose that you have *another problem*. I could analyse it if you would provide the demo, which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Sure, I'll post it as a question and add a note here. Thank you again

Comment: I would be remiss if I did not point out the typo in the last example is in the library, so is correct: "selarrrow" does in fact have 3 character r's in a row. That took a while to debug.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to grab your data from inside a grid event such as `onSelectRow` you can ignore the first part of Oleg's answer and get the data like following:

```
myGrid.jqGrid({
    ... // Grid create options ->
    datatype: 'local',
    data: gridData,  
    // <--
    onSelectRow: function(id){
        data = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", id);

        // if you need actual content of the cells
        // data = myGrid.jqGrid("getRowData", id); 
    }
});
```

Obviously this only works on a single row, however if the intention is **rows**, I believe Oleg's answer is the only choice.

Note: this doesn't work in version 4.5.4 and below however it is fixed in  [oleg's free jqgrid 4.15.2](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid)